# SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException but the database is writable

Tags: android, sqlite, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am using SQLite on Android, ICS. When I make an update, I get a `SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException`. That was weird because i created it with `SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase()`. Also, I tested if the database is readonly just before the update occurs with `myDB.isReadonly()`. This exception doesn't occur on Gingerbread. I suspect it has something to do with different versions of sqlite across android versions.

Here is my code for the creation of the database.

```
protected static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CreateStatements.CREATE_MOVIES);
...

}

public class DBAdapter {
    public static final String PACKAGE_NAME =     
    protected DBHelper dbHelper;
    protected Context context;
    protected SQLiteDatabase myDB;
    public CreateStatements statement;

    public DBAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        myDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        myDB.setLockingEnabled(false);
    }

    public void close() {
        myDB.close();
    }
...

}
```

Comment: I also came across this exact same problem from a client who downloaded my app. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced. Here is how it can be solved:

```
try{
   myDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
} catch (SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException e){
   Log.d(TAG, "SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException");
   startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
}
```

When the database is updated, it retains some connection with the old database. When `new DBHelper(context)` is executed again after database upgrade, the helper links back to the old database. Hence you need to close this class and reinitialize it. In my case MainActivity is the class that first initialized the dbHelper. So when the exception is caught and the activity is restarted, the connection to the old database is removed and it works fine.